# How can I use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in Smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

How can I use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in my Smarty template?

```
// there can not shows the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
{else}
    <h1>{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}</h1>
    {*{include file=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']|cat:'/templates/NeWorld/qicloud_ext/qicloud_products/clientareaproducts_ext/templates/qicloud_dedicate_server.tpl'}*}  // there also do not work
{/if}


// but there works fine, it can import the script
<script type="text/JavaScript" src='{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/templates/NeWorld/qicloud_ext/qicloud_products/clientareaproducts_ext/js/clientareaproducts.js'>
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to re-think your solution and try to do this work in PHP at assign it to smarty for display.

Comment: because the smarty php is closed source, I can not access it. there is extension development.

Comment: smarty has document for it https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty

Comment: `{$smarty.server.DOCUMENT_ROOT}` may work

Comment: @Scuzzy This works, but why the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` can not work?

Comment: Because Smarty isn't PHP, it's its own mini-language.